# running `mtr` network diagnostic tool in the background like `nohup` processes

Tags: networking, tcp, packet-capture, packet-loss

`mtr` is a great tool for debugging the network packet losses. Here i sample mtr output.
`My traceroute  [v0.85]
myserver.com (0.0.0.0)                                                                      Thu Jan 19 04:10:04 2017
Resolver: Received error response 2. (server failure)er of fields   quit
                                                                                              Packets               Pings
 Host                                                                                       Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. 192.168.104.23                                                                           0.0%    11    0.6   0.6   0.5   0.8   0.0
 2. machine1.com                                                                             0.0%    11    8.5  12.4   2.0  20.5   5.5
 3. mchine2.org.com                                                                          0.0%    11    1.2   1.0   0.8   1.8   0.0
 4. machine3.orgcom                                                                          0.0%    11    0.8   0.9   0.7   1.1   0.0`

However while running `mtr` on the server, you can't log-off the server.

I need `mtr` to `output to a textfile` and `run in background` similar to `nohup` command.

I should also be able to look into the report, something like using `tail -f` on the output file.

Answer (score 4):

`mtr` offers `-r` option, which puts `mtr` into report mode. In this mode, `mtr` will run for the number of cycles specified by the `-c` option then print statistics and exit. So we can create a script to run the command and put the script to cron entries on your schedule. For example:

```
/usr/sbin/mtr -r -c 2 www.google.com >> /home/mtr.log
```

Cron entry, run every minute:

```
* * * * * sh /path/to/script
```

Then you can `tail -f` on the output file.

Answer (score 0):

If `systemd` is used

```bash
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$systemd-run --on-calendar=*:*:00  --unit mtr-print-log --slice mtr /usr/sbin/mtr -r -b  192.168.29.154
Running timer as unit mtr-print-log.timer.
Will run service as unit mtr-print-log.service.
```

Viewing `mtr` logs

```bash
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$journalctl -u mtr-print-log.service
-- Logs begin at 六 2022-12-24 21:56:02 CST, end at 六 2022-12-24 22:10:19 CST. --
12月 24 22:07:00 vms81.liruilongs.github.io systemd[1]: Started /usr/sbin/mtr -r -b 192.168.29.154.
12月 24 22:07:14 vms81.liruilongs.github.io mtr[15427]: Start: Sat Dec 24 22:07:00 2022
12月 24 22:07:14 vms81.liruilongs.github.io mtr[15427]: HOST: vms81.liruilongs.github.io  Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
12月 24 22:07:14 vms81.liruilongs.github.io mtr[15427]: 1.|-- gateway (192.168.26.2)     0.0%    10    0.4   0.3   0.2   0.5   0.0
12月 24 22:07:14 vms81.liruilongs.github.io mtr[15427]: 2.|-- 192.168.29.154             0.0%    10    1.5   0.9   0.7   1.5   0.0
12月 24 22:08:00 vms81.liruilongs.github.io systemd[1]: Started /usr/sbin/mtr -r -b 192.168.29.154.
12月 24 22:08:14 vms81.liruilongs.github.io mtr[16400]: Start: Sat Dec 24 22:08:00 2022
12月 24 22:08:14 vms81.liruilongs.github.io mtr[16400]: HOST: vms81.liruilongs.github.io  Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
12月 24 22:08:14 vms81.liruilongs.github.io mtr[16400]: 1.|-- gateway (192.168.26.2)     0.0%    10    0.3   0.3   0.2   0.4   0.0
12月 24 22:08:14 vms81.liruilongs.github.io mtr[16400]: 2.|-- 192.168.29.154             0.0%    10    1.0   1.0   0.7   1.4   0.0
12月 24 22:09:00 vms81.liruilongs.github.io systemd[1]: Started /usr/sbin/mtr -r -b 192.168.29.154.
12月 24 22:09:14 vms81.liruilongs.github.io mtr[17411]: Start: Sat Dec 24 22:09:00 2022
12月 24 22:09:14 vms81.liruilongs.github.io mtr[17411]: HOST: vms81.liruilongs.github.io  Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
12月 24 22:09:14 vms81.liruilongs.github.io mtr[17411]: 1.|-- gateway (192.168.26.2)     0.0%    10    0.3   0.3   0.3   0.5   0.0
12月 24 22:09:14 vms81.liruilongs.github.io mtr[17411]: 2.|-- 192.168.29.154             0.0%    10    0.9   0.9   0.7   1.3   0.0
```

If you only want to see the output and the execution time, you can.

```bash
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$journalctl -u  mtr-print-log.service -o cat | tail -n 10
Started /usr/sbin/mtr -r -b 192.168.29.154.
Start: Sat Dec 24 22:13:00 2022
HOST: vms81.liruilongs.github.io  Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
1.|-- gateway (192.168.26.2)     0.0%    10    0.2   0.3   0.2   0.5   0.0
2.|-- 192.168.29.154             0.0%    10    0.8   0.8   0.7   1.1   0.0
Started /usr/sbin/mtr -r -b 192.168.29.154.
Start: Sat Dec 24 22:14:00 2022
HOST: vms81.liruilongs.github.io  Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
1.|-- gateway (192.168.26.2)     0.0%    10    0.3   0.3   0.2   0.4   0.0
2.|-- 192.168.29.154             0.0%    10    0.9   0.8   0.7   1.0   0.0
```

Delete `mtr` process

```bash
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$systemctl stop mtr-print-log.timer
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$systemctl is-active mtr-print-log.service
unknown
```